# counting the site visitors not working

Tags: php

I use these following codes in main `index.php` of my site to get the number of visitors :

```
    <?php
$file = "counts.html";

    if ( is_file( $file )==false )  {touch($file);$open = fopen($file, "w");fwrite($open, "0");fclose($open);}

//read counts
$open = fopen($file, "r");
$count = fread($open, filesize($file));
fclose($open);

//if cookie isn't already set,then increase counts by one + save ip, and set a cookie to pc...
$cookie_namee='mycounterr-456';
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_namee])) {
    $open = fopen($file, "w");
    $count++;
    fwrite($open, $count);
    fclose($open);
    setcookie($cookie_namee,"Checked",time()+111400);
    }

//uncomment the below line to see the visits number on page
echo $count;
?>
```

It sometimes works, sometimes not working. Is there anything that i'm doing that in a wrong way?

**EDIT :** I found the problem. It seems the code works, but the problem is that the value won't overwrite the existing value in `counts.html`

The file only writes 0 for the first time and it won't change 0 at all.

How can I fix this problem?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I strongly recommend to store "data" in a "data base"

Comment: @bub it should work. cause it will save data in a .html file. it used to work great on other sites, before. but this time for another site, not working like that

Comment: Same host? There are some security issues here and if I was the hosting provider I'd not give the *www-data* user permissions to create/write files under the document root (normally).

Comment: @CD001 What should i do?

Comment: @bub hits the nail on the head I'm afraid, with "use a database". If you're simply creating a logging file then that should **not** be under the document root, or at least buried in a folder with a `Deny from all` restriction on - it shouldn't be available to world+dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must add `session_start();` in your first line of your codes.

It's better to save the counter numbers to `.txt` file than `.html` file.

Now change your codes to the following codes :

```
    <?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counts.txt";

if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}

// Read the counter values
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Check if visitor has been counted in this session
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
  $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
  $counterVal++;
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Still should also look into `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` for codesize, performance  and security

Comment: Or even better: `if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE || session_id() == '') {session_start();}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look much cleaner and will run safer if using the `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` function:

```
<?php

session_start();
$file = "counts.txt";
$count = 0;
$cookie_namee = 'mycounterr-456';

if ($content = @file_get_contents($file))
    $count = intval($content);

echo "count is $count at start<br />";

//if cookie isn't already set,then increase counts by one + save ip, and set a cookie to pc...
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_namee])) {
    $count++;
    file_put_contents($file, "$count");
    echo "updating $file with $count<br />";
    setcookie($cookie_namee,"Checked",time()+111400);
}

//uncomment the below line to see the visits number on page
echo $count;

?>
```

There are better ways to implement a counter, but this could work :)

Comment: had a mistake in the file_get_contents compare, which is fixed now and i added echo so you can see what is going wrong. works for me.

Comment: I found the problem. It seems the code works, but the problem is that the value won't overwrite the existing value in counts.html. How can I fix that?

Comment: if i use `if (true || !isset(...` so that the counter is always written then with the above code the counter is updated, so the problem is with your cookie - or are you getting the `echo "updating..` output but file is not written?

Comment: the file only write 0 for the first time and 0 won't change

Comment: with my code as well? because here it works. try deleting the html file and running again. but the above code snippet is tested under Apache 2 and PHP 5.5 with Safari - also check file permissions for www user

Comment: still not working. I don't know why? I use exactly that codes in other site and work great. maybe you're right it's about file permissions. how can I check that?

Comment: linux? mac? windows? :)

Comment: check out http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7 - also make sure the the directory in which files are, has same permissions

Answer (score 0):

So much code IMHO

```
$file = "counts.html"; // Why html?
$cookie_namee = 'mycounterr-456';
$count = file_get_contents( $file );

if( !isset( $_COOKIE[ $cookie_namee ] ) ) {
  $count++;
  file_put_contents( $file, $count );

  setcookie( $cookie_namee, 1, time() + 111400 );
}

echo $count;
```

Comment: I found the problem. It seems the code works, but the problem is that the value won't overwrite the existing value in counts.html. How can I fix that?

Comment: Just remove 2 lines "if( !isset( $_COOKIE[ $cookie_namee ] ) ) {" and "}" it's looks like you allready have this cookie so you count only once : )